# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'quizController' is not registered

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

I'm getting Error:

> [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'quizController' is not registered.

quizController.js:

```
angular.module("quizApp",[])
    .controller("quizController", function($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello World";
    });
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="quizApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="quizController">
<!-- <h1>hello world please work!</h1>  -->
{{message}}
  <script src="src/libs.js"></script>
  <script src="src/scripts.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have not included quizController.js in your index.html

Answer (score 0):

Change your index.html accordingly. Also, make sure that you have your imports sorted.

```
    <div ng-app="quizApp">
      <h1>Controllers</h1>
      <div ng-controller="quizController">
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<script src="quizController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please explain, how this code solves the problem described in the question?

Comment: The formatting of the HTML looked off to me. He should also get his imports sorted as that is what is causing the error.

Comment: It is based on AngularJS 1.x , so there are no 'imports'

Comment: In that case adding  <script src="quizController.js"></script>.

Comment: I had a similar issue in angular 5. However, it was a simple fix of adding the required imports into app-module.ts